# Using laravel constants as default value for arguments in a function

Tags: php, laravel, constants, laravel-8

I am converting my old PHP project into a Laravel based project.
In my old project I had defined constants in a config file which was loaded in each page. I would define the constants in a file like this.

```
define('USER_IMAGES_DIR', IMAGES_DIR."user_images/");
define("POST_IMAGES_DIR", IMAGES_DIR."post_images/");
define("FONTS_DIR", ASSET_DIR."fonts/");
```

Whenever I need to use the constants in a function I would directly do it like this.

```
function make_avatar($character,$storepath=USER_IMAGES_DIR,$extension='png')
    {
        $image_name=time() . '.'.$extension;
        $path = $storepath. $image_name;
        $image = imagecreate(200, 200);
        $red = rand(0, 255);
        $green = rand(0, 255);
        $blue = rand(0, 255);
        imagecolorallocate($image, $red, $green, $blue);
        $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 255,255,255);
        imagettftext($image, 100, 0, 55, 150, $textcolor,FONTS_DIR.'arial.ttf', $character);
        imagepng($image, $path);
        imagedestroy($image);
        return $image_name;
    }
```

Now, in laravel, the constants are stored in the config folder and are accessed through the global helpers like `config('app_images_dir')`. I try to use the global helper directly inside a function's default value like this.

```
function make_avatar($character,$storepath=config('app.user_images_dir'),$extension='png')
    {
        $image_name=time() . '.'.$extension;
        $path = $storepath. $image_name;
        $image = imagecreate(200, 200);
        $red = rand(0, 255);
        $green = rand(0, 255);
        $blue = rand(0, 255);
        imagecolorallocate($image, $red, $green, $blue);
        $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 255,255,255);
        imagettftext($image, 100, 0, 55, 150, $textcolor,FONTS_DIR.'arial.ttf', $character);
        imagepng($image, $path);
        imagedestroy($image);
        return $image_name;
    }
```

However, now when I try to use the constants as a default value for the function it cannot be used and shows error.
I get error which says `Constant expression contains invalid operations`
So, my question is how can I use this constants the same way I used in my traditional project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With due respect to all the given answers. I want to add my method which you may find as helpful.

config helper itself is a function. The rule of the function in PHP is that its default value must be an absolute value and not a relative value or a function. In other words the default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call. Therefore the function cannot contain default value using config() since it is a function. What you can do however is, tweak your code a little bit.

If the function you are using is not inside of  class then you can define a constant above the function and use it later in the function.

```
define('USER_IMAGES_DIR', config('app.user_images_dir'));
```

Use this value in the function in this way.

```
function make_avatar($character,$storepath=USER_IMAGES_DIR,$extension='png')
    {
        $image_name=time() . '.'.$extension;
        $path = $storepath. $image_name;
        $image = imagecreate(200, 200);
        $red = rand(0, 255);
        $green = rand(0, 255);
        $blue = rand(0, 255);
        imagecolorallocate($image, $red, $green, $blue);
        $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 255,255,255);
        imagettftext($image, 100, 0, 55, 150, $textcolor,FONTS_DIR.'arial.ttf', $character);
        imagepng($image, $path);
        imagedestroy($image);
        return $image_name;
    }
```

Incase this function is inside of a class, then you can create a constant and then use this as your default function value using the self keyword

```
public class MyHelper extends Helper
{
    protected const path=config('app.user_images_dir') ;  


 public function make_avatar($character, $storepath = self::path, $extension = 'png')
    {
        $image_name=time() . '.'.$extension;
            $path = $storepath. $image_name;
            $image = imagecreate(200, 200);
            $red = rand(0, 255);
            $green = rand(0, 255);
            $blue = rand(0, 255);
            imagecolorallocate($image, $red, $green, $blue);
            $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 255,255,255);
            imagettftext($image, 100, 0, 55, 150, $textcolor,FONTS_DIR.'arial.ttf', $character);
            imagepng($image, $path);
            imagedestroy($image);
            return $image_name;
    }
}
```

In other way you can also check for the value inside of the function to see if it has been called or not.

```
public class MyHelper extends Helper
{
  
  /*changed the variable order so that you can still call function without sending storepath varible*/
         public function make_avatar($character, $extension = 'png',$storepath = null )
            {
                $image_name=time() . '.'.$extension;
                //check if storepath is null
                  $storepath=$storepath?$storepath:config('app.user_images_dir');
                    $path = $storepath. $image_name;
                    $image = imagecreate(200, 200);
                    $red = rand(0, 255);
                    $green = rand(0, 255);
                    $blue = rand(0, 255);
                    imagecolorallocate($image, $red, $green, $blue);
                    $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 255,255,255);
                    imagettftext($image, 100, 0, 55, 150, $textcolor,FONTS_DIR.'arial.ttf', $character);
                    imagepng($image, $path);
                    imagedestroy($image);
                    return $image_name;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting a default value for the path in the `constructor` and then handling a `null` value in your `make_avatar` function.

```php
class Avatar
{
    private $storepath ;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->storepath = config('app.user_images_dir');
    }

    public function make_avatar($character, $storepath = null, $extension = 'png')
    {
        $image_name = time() . '.'.$extension;
        $path = $storepath ?? $this->storepath . $image_name;
        ...
    }
}
```

What we're doing here is using the null coalescing operator (`??`) to check if the `$storepath` arguement is `null` or not. If `$storepath` is not `null` we use its value, otherwise use the `config` value.

Alternatively if you do not intend on using `$storepath` anywhere else other than in `make_avatar`, you could not bother setting a class property in the constructor and so replace `$this->storepath` with the `config` accessor:

```php
$path = $storepath ?? config('app.user_images_dir') . $image_name;
```

Something to note is that you have two optional parameters and if you want to change the default value of `$extension`, you'll still need to provide a value for `$storepath` when using `make_avatar`:

```php
$instanceOfAvatar->make_avatar('foo', null, 'jpeg');
```

Unless you're using PHP 8 and [named arguments](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-named-arguments).